# Creating Dynamic Function

Tags: c#

I have recreated the class below its a fully functional example of what I am currently trying to accomplish. Create a Console Application using .Net Framework 4.5. There has been much help along the way and I wanted to make a working example for others that might stumble along this post. Once everything is in order I will mark the top of the solution with *FIXED.

```
//*FIXED AND WORKING added benchmark for each variation available only issue is the delegates are slower then MethodInfo.Invoke
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MethodInfoToDelgateInvocation
{
    class Program
    {
        static FindMethods findMethods = new FindMethods();
        static DelegateRef delegateRef = new DelegateRef();
        static Test test = new Test();
        static Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            findMethods.FindNow(new Test());
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                test.HelloWorld(35, "Too Cool", 5.11F);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Direct Invoke Time {sw.Elapsed}");
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                //Test to see if delegateRef will fire off the TestMethod
                delegateRef.DelegateReference.Method.Invoke(delegateRef.Class, new object[3] { 35, "Too Cool", 5.11F });
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Delegate.Method.Invoke Time {sw.Elapsed}");
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                delegateRef.DelegateReference.DynamicInvoke(new object[3] { 35, "Too Cool", 5.11F });
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Delegate.DynamicInvoke Time {sw.Elapsed}");
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();            
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                delegateRef.Method.Invoke(delegateRef.Class, new object[3] { 35, "Too Cool", 5.11F });
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"MethodInfo.Invoke Time {sw.Elapsed}");
            sw.Reset();
            ConsoleKeyInfo key;
            do
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey();
            } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
        }
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Method)]
        public class RSync : Attribute
        {
        }
        public class DelegateRef
        {
            public int ClassId;
            public int Index;
            public Delegate DelegateReference;
            public MethodInfo Method;
            public object Class;
        }
        public class Test
        {
            [RSync]
            public void HelloWorld(int age, string name, float height)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine($"Age {age} Name {name} Height {height}");
            }
        }
        public class FindMethods
        {
            public void FindNow(Test test)
            {
                const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
                | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.GetProperty;
                var methods = test.GetType().GetMethods().Where(methodInfo => methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RSync), true).Length > 0).ToList();
                var fields = test.GetType().GetFields(flags).Where(fieldInfo => fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RSync), true).Length > 0).ToList();
                if (methods.Count == 0 && fields.Count == 0) return;

                foreach (var methodInfo in methods)
                {
                    //shingo's ideology mixed with Adassko expression tree idea
                    var actionType = Expression.GetActionType(methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
                    Console.WriteLine($"Action type {actionType}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"MethodInfo {methodInfo}");
                    delegateRef.DelegateReference = Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, null, methodInfo);
                    delegateRef.Method = methodInfo;
                    delegateRef.Class = test;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> BenchMark ("What am I doing wrong shouldnt the delegate be faster?")

```
Direct Invoke Time 00:00:00.0405356
Delegate.Method.Invoke Time 00:00:04.3252286
Delegate.DynamicInvoke Time 00:00:17.3568062
MethodInfo.Invoke Time 00:00:03.9669439
```

> Big thank you to all those that had helped me get this working.. (Upvote's to everyone.) If the Delegate can be invoked more efficiently I would love to know.

```
Adassko
Alexei Levenkov
Shingo
Tymtam
```

Comment: you're probably looking for expression trees https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/

Comment: Are you trying https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+create+generic+type+run-time? (Very confusing what you want to achieve overall, but `MakeGenericType` should get you going based on a way I interpret the question)...

Comment: these answers should fit your requirements well

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but are you after something like this?

```
var fs = new List<Func<string, int>>();

int f1(string s) { return s.Length; };
int f2(string s) { return s.Length * 2; };

fs.Add(f1);
fs.Add(f2);

foreach(var f in fs )
{
    Console.WriteLine(f("Is this it?"));
}
```

Output:

```
11
22
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [Type.MakeGenericType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netframework-4.8)

```
public static Type GetDelegateType(Type[] paramTypes, bool noReturnType)
{
    if(noReturnType) //Action
    {
        switch (paramTypes.Length)
        {
            case 0: return typeof(Action);
            case 1: return typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(paramTypes);
            case 2: return typeof(Action<,>).MakeGenericType(paramTypes);
            ...
        }
    }
    else //Func
    {
        switch (paramTypes.Length)
        {
            case 1: return typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(paramTypes);
            case 2: return typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(paramTypes);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```